# Calculation of $\frac {1-q^{n+1}}{1-q} \times \frac {1-q^{n+2}}{1-q}$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am trying to solve this equation:

$$\sum^{n}_{i=0} q^i \times \frac {1-q^{n+2}}{1-q}  = \frac {1-q^{n+1}}{1-q} \times \frac {1-q^{n+2}}{1-q} = \frac {1-q^{n}q^1}{1-q} \times \frac {1-q^{n}q^2}{1-q} = ...?$$

where 
$$\sum^{n}_{i=0} q^i = \frac {1-q^{n+1}}{1-q}$$

However, I am stuck at the last part. Can I simplify this even more. How to do that?

I really appreciate your answers!!

Comment: Wait is that your whole equation? Or one of the sides?

Comment: Its one of the sites...

Comment: What's the other?

Comment: Ok updated my answer! With the whole equation...

Comment: I'm still confused... are you trying to solve an equation, or just simplify an expression?

Comment: @user7530 I am trying to simplify the expression if this is further possible...

Comment: Ok. I don't think there's anything simpler than $\frac{(1-q^{n+1})(1-q^{n+2})}{(1-q)^2}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Before question was edited:**
This looks like the multiplication of two Geometric Progressions:
$$(1+q^1+q^2.....+q^{(n)} ).(1+q^1+q^2.....+q^{(n+1)} )$$